Angular: Accessing Parent Directive in Recursive List Rendered with ngTemplateOutlet
I'm working with a template to display a nested list, like this:
const tree = [
  { label: "A" },
  { label: "B" },
  {
    label: "C",
    children: [
      { label: "C0" },
      { label: "C1" },
      { label: "C2" },
    ],
  },
  { label: "D" },
  { label: "E" },
  {
    label: "F",
    children: [
      { label: "F0" },
      {
        label: "F1",
        children: [
          { label: "F1-0" },
          {
            label: "F1-1",
            children: [
              { label: "F1-1-0" },
              { label: "F1-1-1" },
              { label: "F1-1-2" },
            ],
          },
          { label: "F1-2" },
        ],
      },
      { label: "F2" },
    ],
  },
];

And here’s my HTML template:
<ul>
  <ng-template #itemTemplate let-entry>
    <li myDirective>{{ entry.label }}
      <ng-container *ngIf="entry.children && entry.children.length">
        <ul>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let child of entry.children">
            <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate; context: { $implicit: child }"></ng-template>
          </ng-container>
        </ul>
      </ng-container>
    </li>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of tree">
    <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate; context: { $implicit: item }"></ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</ul>

My goal is to retrieve the parent myDirective instance from a child myDirective instance. In the constructor of myDirective, I tried using:
@Optional() @SkipSelf() private parentItem?: MyDirective | null;

This works only when the tree is explicitly rendered, without using a template. Otherwise, the dependency hierarchy seems to be lost.
So, my question is: How can I obtain a reference to the directive instance of a parent element from within a child element rendered through a template?
For example, how can I access the directive instance for "F1-1" from within the directive instance of "F1-1-0"?

My solution does not involve dependency injection, but passing the reference through the ng-template and ng-container, we use exportAs property of the directive to get the component scope and setting to a templateReferenceVariable(directiveScope) and pass it along to that.
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]',
  exportAs: 'myDirective',
})
export class MyDirective {
  ...
}

We pass the this into the context as a property called that.
<ul>
  <ng-template #itemTemplate let-entry let-that="that">
    <li myDirective #directiveScope="myDirective">{{ entry.label }}
      <ng-container *ngIf="entry.children && entry.children.length">
        <ul>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let child of entry.children">
            <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate; context: { $implicit: child, that: directiveScope }"></ng-template>
          </ng-container>
        </ul>
      </ng-container>
    </li>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of tree">
    <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate; context: { $implicit: item, that: null }"></ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</ul>

